# The difference between sparse matrix by linked list representation and array representation

Tags: arrays, linked-list, sparse-matrix

Are there any difference(advantage/disadvantage) between sparse matrix by linked-list representation and array representation?

Linked-list representation stores the row and column link like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgXY3.png

Array stores the row, column, and value.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very general question. It is like asking if linked lists are better than arrays. There is no answer to such a question.

Sparse matrix packages that I have seen might use either or both formats internally, depends on the case. Even if you just use arrays, you can use CSC, CSR or triplet format. The performance can vary in different applications and it is usually closely connected to cache usage.